# Regex for two latitudes and longitudes not working

Tags: php, mysql, regex, google-maps, preg-match

I am using some data which gives paths for google maps either as a path or a set of two latitudes and longitudes. I have stored both values as a BLOB in a mySql database, but I need to detect the values which are not paths when they come out in the result. In an attempt to do this, I have saved them in the BLOB in the following format:

> array(lat,lng+lat,lng)

I am using preg_match to find these results, but i havent managed to get any to work. Here are the regex codes I have tried:

```
^[a]{1}[r]{2}[a]{1}[y]{1}[\(]{1}[1-9\.\,\+]{1*}[\)]{1}^

^[a]{1}[r]{2}[a]{1}[y]{1}[\(]{1}(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\+(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)[\)]{1}^
```

Regex confuses me sometimes (as it is doing now). Can anyone help me out?

**Edit:**

The lat can be 2 digits followed by a decimal point and 8 more digits and the lng can be 3 digits can be 3 digits follwed by a decimal point and 8 more digits. Both can be positive or negative.

Here are some example lat lngs:

> 51.51160000,-0.12766000
>
> -53.36442000,132.27519000
>
> 51.50628000,0.12699000
>
> -51.50628000,-0.12699000

So a full match would look like:

> array(51.51160000,-0.12766000+-53.36442000,132.27519000)

**Further Edit**

I am using the preg_match() php function to match the regex.

Comment: whoa. overkill. Just a single character such as `a` represents itself. You only need character classes (characters between square brackets) if you need to represent more than one character. So `array` is the same as `[a]{1}[r]{2}[a]{1}[y]{1}` in regex.

Comment: Could you provide a list of actual inputs that you're trying to match?  I'm not sure what format the `lat` and `lng` are expected to be in.

Comment: why is text in a blob, why did you not store them separately?

Comment: @Dagon because some of the paths can be extremely long, as they are code to draw lines across google maps, sometimes half way around the world

Comment: there are different ways to store geodata in mysql like geospatial types or (geo)JSON, I can't imagine a more unsuitable format than yours. Furthermore: two lat/lng-pairs are a path too, what's the purpose of this differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex I made:

```
array\((-*\d+\.\d+),(-*\d+\.\d+)\+(-*\d+\.\d+),(-*\d+\.\d+)\)
```

This also breaks the four numbers into groups so you can get the individual numbers.

You will note the repeated pattern of

```
(-*\d+\.\d+)
```

Explanation:

```
-* means 0 or more matches of the - sign ( so - sign is optional)
\d+ means 1 or more matches of a number
\. means a literal period (decimal)
\d+ means 1 or more matches of a number
```

The whole thing is wrapped in brackets to make it a captured group.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some pointers for writing regex:

If you have a single possibility for a character, for example, the `a` in array, you can indeed write it as `[a]`; however, you can also write it as just `a`.

If you are looking to match exactly one of something, you can indeed write it as `a{1}`, however, you can also write it as just `a`.

Applying this lots, your example of `^[a]{1}[r]{2}[a]{1}[y]{1}[\(]{1}[1-9\.\,\+]{1*}[\)]{1}^` reduces to `^array\([1-9\.\,\+]{1*}\)^` - that's certainly an improvement!

Next, numbers may also include 0's, as well as 1-9. In fact, `\d` - any digit - is usually used instead of `1-9`.

You are using `^` as the delimiter - usually that is `/`;  I didn't recognize it at first. I'm not sure what you can use for the delimiter, so, just in case, I'll change it to the usual `/`.This makes the above regex `/array\([\d\.\,\+]{1*}\)/`.

To match one or more of a character or character set, use `+`, rather than `{1*}`. This makes your query `/array\([\d\.\,\+]+\)/`

Then, to collect the resulting numbers (assuming you want only the part between the brackets, put it in (non-escaped) brackets, thus: `/array\(([\d\.\,\+]+)\)/` - you would then need to split them, first by `+`, then by `,`. Alternatively, if there are exactly two lat,lng pairs, you might want: `/array\(([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+)\+([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+)\)/` - this will return 4 values, one for each number; the additional stuff (`+`, `,`) will already be removed, because it is not in (unescaped) brackets `()`.

Edit: If you want negative lats and longs (and why wouldn't you?) you will need `\-?` (a "literal -", rather than part of a range) in the appropriate places; the `?` makes it optional (i.e. 0 or 1 dashes). For example, `/array\((\-?[\d\.]+),(\-?[\d\.]+)\+(\-?[\d\.]+),(\-?[\d\.]+)\)/`

You might also want to check out http://regexpal.com - you can put in a regex and a set of strings, and it will highlight what matches/doesn't match. You will need to exclude the delimiter `/` or `^`.

Note that this is a little fast and loose; it would also match `array(5,0+0,1...........)`. You can nail it down a little more, for example, by using `(\-?\d*\.\d+)\)` instead of `(\-?[\d\.]+)\)` for the numbers; that will match (0 or 1 literal `-`) followed by (0 or more digits) followed by (exactly one literal dot) followed by (1 or more digits).

Comment: Thanks for this! Using the last one, it still won't work as php preg_match expects the ^ delimiter, as this is the first delimiter?

Comment: Ah, it's the delimiter. Usually `/` is used for that. I'd forgotten about the delimiter.